# How can I style an HTML scrollbar like the one sometimes found on google SERPs?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

i was googling when i came across this.. the following image & never before or after that saw it...

this is a screen shot of google results in firefox

[image]

one result was scrollable with in itself...

see the scroll bar.. how can i achieve this scroll-bar...

we can have scrolling inside Divs but Firefox doesn't let CSS styling of scroll-bar & it screws the look & feel of the page...

Comment: Try asking on http://doctype.com/  Questions about programming are more relevant on stackoverflow.  This is a design question at heart.

Comment: the one who voted to close must know that i am looking for a possibly unknown component or some unknown coding\building technique

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery UI can knock this out of the park.  Check out their [slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll).

All of their widgets are ARIA-enabled and keyboard accessible, try using arrow keys and page-up/page-down on the example.

You can get this working on your website in 20 minutes.  Less if you are already familiar with jQuery UI.

Answer (score 3):

In webkit browsers, you can use the [`::-webkit-scrollbar`](http://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/) css selector

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own scroll bar and `div` using JavaScript - currently, styling scrollbars only works in IE5.

Comment: Not true. Webkit (ie, Safari, Google Chrome) allows you to [style the scrollbar](http://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/) as well (albeit in a different and more customizable way)

Comment: Oops. Missed that out. Still, like a lot of other styling stuff, it's not totally cross browser, which can disrupt continuity and can be less than ideal for some developers.